# AutoLayout for viewcontroller's xib?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5, autolayout

I m confused about the usage of `AutoLayout`.I couldn't understand when to use it and when not to .I m developing an app in Xcode 4.5 and when I test it on prevoius versions of simulators(4.3,5.0)etc the app crashes with this exception "

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint "
```

I have gone through Google and found this happens when `Use AutoLayout` is checked in xib.

But when I uncheck this `Use Autolayout` I dont get any exception.

But when I test the app in retina4 inch I dont get the view's content starting from the top.It starts from the middle.I mean to say the design is not the same when tested for nonretina and retina.So for that purpose I have kept `'Use AutoLayout'` in `checked` state.

What can I do to get both my conditions satisfied?I need to make it compatible with all versions of simulators...

Any help woud be appreciable/thankful...

Comment: You couldn't use autolayout before ios 6. If you want to use autolayout before ios6 in that case app will be crash.

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone 5's 4 inch display you'll need a third default image Default-568h@2x.png. Otherwise the views will be letterboxed. To support iOS versions prior to iOS6 you need autolayout option to be disabled, but that means, that you'll have to have autoresizing mask set up properly or/in addition to that update views manually in code depending on the screen size.

Comment: I have already added Default-568h@2x.png for iphone 4 inch.Can u please tell me where can I set autoresizing mask set up properly.Do I need to write each and every section of code separatley depending on the screen size .I mean do I need to write separate code for creation of same textbox in iphone 4 and iphone 5 separately .?

Comment: You'll need just to update the screen size and those big elements like views or tableViews. And, of course if you need some specific behavior (like buttons on the bottom of the screen) you'll have to update their frames as well.

Comment: And about autoresizing mask: check size inspector and that rectangle with red lines (Autoresizing and Example with red animated rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

**Use Autolayout** is an option given by Apple to automatically set the layout of your nib file from iOS  6.0 onwards. So if you are going to give support for iOS versions lower than that the OS will not be able to find it and hence will result in a crash.

So Its an option which you can use if you are giving support to **only iOS 6.0 and onwards**.

Answer (score 0):

You can load different **XIB's** for your ***viewController***. For **3.5 inch** follow the steps

```
1. Select your xib, first unchecked auto-layout.
2. Select View object and in its property window, change size property and set it to Retuina 3.5 full screen.
3. Make changes in your code to load your XIB's for different devices.
```

Comment: I m developing for ipad and iphone.In iphone I have already written code if it is iphone 3.5 and iphone 4 bcoz I have a UITabbar in my app I need to adjust it separately based on the height of iphone screen size but loaded the same xib with autolayout checked.So I have two xibs now (one for iphone and one for iPad).Can u tell me   should I  take 3 xibs now (iPad,iphone 3.5,iphone 4 )

Comment: hey I have a small doubt.What if I uncheck 'Use AutoLayout' for iphone 4 inch display and handle springs and struts in the same xib without creating new xib?Because when I uncheck it and test in iphone5 its working and same when I check it in iphone4 inch also its working because I have made all springs and struts(left,right,bottom,top)(width,height) and the view doesn't start from middle.Its aligned correctly.Do I need to take separate xibs now also?

Comment: no you will not need different xib's if you handling your control's position.